# Metadata error when trying to ng serve a website

Tags: angular

This might be too specific an error to receive help with, but I'm posting here looking for any suggestion on what to do.

I'm migrating websites from a previous layout to a new layout (with similar functionality) to Angular 4. On my previous machine everything was running as expected. I received a new machine and now whenever I try to serve the website I receive a block of errors.

```
ERROR in Error: Metadata version mismatch for module C:/Users/drose/Angular/node_modules/@ng-idle/keepalive/index.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol AppModule in C:/Users/drose/Angular/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in C:/Users/drose/Angular/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in C:/Users/drose/Angular/src/app/app.module.ts
at syntaxError (C:\Users\drose\Angular\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:1729:34)
at simplifyInContext (C:\Users\drose\Angular\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24979:23)
at StaticReflector.simplify (C:\Users\drose\Angular\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24991:13)
at StaticReflector.annotations (C:\Users\drose\Angular\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24418:41)
at _getNgModuleMetadata (C:\Users\drose\Angular\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:138:31)
at _extractLazyRoutesFromStaticModule (C:\Users\drose\Angular\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:109:26)
at Object.listLazyRoutesOfModule (C:\Users\drose\Angular\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:53:22)
at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.listLazyRoutes (C:\Users\drose\Angular\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_api.js:91:39)
at AotPlugin._getLazyRoutesFromNgtools (C:\Users\drose\Angular\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:241:66)
at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then.then.then.then.then (C:\Users\drose\Angular\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:495:24)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

I've tried manually installing every dependency, reinstalling different versions of node, grabbing a previous version of the website from out github history and nothing seems to work. Anyone have more experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you used the old versions. You have to update the new versions in your `package.json`

```
"@angular/cdk": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^4.0.0",

// update whatever other modules to latest version
```

For further info check [this](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/8229)